# Python console must be restarted after successful process completion?

Tags: python

I created a wrapper class to handle `AWS Redshift` loads, and after it completes the load, it returns a 0, and then does not offer a prompt to keep working in the terminal.

```
2016-03-04 11:17:56,013 [INFO] - Test load triggered, connecting now to staging_ipeds_k12_faculty_counts.
2016-03-04 11:17:56,013 [INFO] - Accessing ods_ipeds.staging_ipeds_k12_faculty_counts
2016-03-04 11:18:01,653 [INFO] - Load to the development database was a success.
2016-03-04 11:18:01,653 [INFO] - Commencing load operation to staging_ipeds_k12_faculty_counts.
2016-03-04 11:18:01,653 [INFO] - Accessing ods_ipeds.staging_ipeds_k12_faculty_counts
2016-03-04 11:18:05,407 [INFO] - Load to the production database was a success.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Is there a way to make it not stop my prompt?  I have to restart it currently, which resets my environment, variables, etc...  I'm working in `IPython`.

Here is the class I'm calling:

```
class LoadToRedshift(object):

    def __init__(self,
                 schema_name,
                 table,
                 manifest_url,
                 s3_credentials,
                 redshift_db_credentials,
                 dev_db_credentials=None,
                 safe_load=False,
                 truncate=False):
        """
        This class automates the copy of data from an S3 file to a Redshift
        database.  Most of the methods are static, and can be accessed outside
        the class.  Run the 'execute' method to run the process.

        :param schema_name: The schema name associated with the desired table.
        :param table: The Redshift table name.
        :param manifest_url: The location of the file on S3.
        :param s3_credentials: A dictionary containing the access and
        secret access keys.  Keys must match the example:

        S3_INFO = {
        'aws_access_key_id': S3_ACCESS,
        'aws_secret_access_key': S3_SECRET,
        'region_name': 'us-west-2'
        }

        :param redshift_db_credentials: A dictionary containing the host, port,
        database name, username, and password.  Keys must match example:

        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO = {
            'host': REDSHIFT_HOST,
            'port': REDSHIFT_PORT,
            'database': REDSHIFT_DATABASE_DEV,
            'user': REDSHIFT_USER,
            'password': REDSHIFT_PASS
        }

        :param safe_load: If True will trigger a test load to a specified
        development database during the 'full_load' method.  Useful for making
        sure the data will correctly load before truncating the production
        database.
        :param truncate: If 'True', the production table will be truncated
        before the copy step.

        :return: None
        """
        self.schema_name = schema_name
        self.table_name = table
        self.manifest_url = manifest_url
        self.s3_creds = s3_credentials
        self.prod_db_creds = redshift_db_credentials
        self.dev_db_creds = dev_db_credentials
        self.safe_load = safe_load
        self.truncate = truncate

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('Schema Name: {}\nTable: {}\nManifest URL:'
                ' {}\nS3 Credentials: {}\nDev DB Credentials: {}\nProd DB '
                'Credentials: {}\nSafe Load: {}\nTruncate: {}'.format(
            self.schema_name, self.table_name, self.manifest_url,
            self.s3_creds, self.dev_db_creds, self.prod_db_creds,
            self.safe_load, self.truncate
        ))

    @staticmethod
    def copy_to_db(database_credentials,
                   schema_name,
                   table_name,
                   manifest_url,
                   s3_credentials,
                   truncate=False):
        """
        Copies data from a file on S3 to a Redshift table.  Data must be
        properly formatted and in the right order, etc...

        :param database_credentials: A dictionary containing the host, port,
        database name, username, and password.  Keys must match example:

        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO = {
            'host': REDSHIFT_HOST,
            'port': REDSHIFT_PORT,
            'database': REDSHIFT_DATABASE_DEV,
            'user': REDSHIFT_USER,
            'password': REDSHIFT_PASS
        }

        :param schema_name: The Redshift schema name.
        :param table_name: The Redshift table name.
        :param manifest_url: The location of the file on the S3 server.
        :param s3_credentials: A dictionary containing the access and
        secret access keys.  Keys must match the example:

        S3_INFO = {
        'aws_access_key_id': S3_ACCESS,
        'aws_secret_access_key': S3_SECRET,
        'region_name': 'us-west-2'
        }

        :param truncate: If 'True', will cause the table to be truncated before
        the load.

        :return: None
        """
        s3_access = s3_credentials['aws_access_key_id']
        s3_secret = s3_credentials['aws_secret_access_key']

        logging.info('Accessing {}'.format(schema_name + '.' + table_name))
        try:
            with ppg2.connect(**database_credentials) as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()

                if truncate:
                    LoadToRedshift.truncate_table(schema_name, table_name, cur)

                load='''
                copy {}.{}
                from '{}'
                credentials 'aws_access_key_id={};aws_secret_access_key={}'
                delimiter '|'
                gzip
                trimblanks
                truncatecolumns
                acceptinvchars
                timeformat 'auto'
                dateformat 'auto'
                '''.format(
                schema_name, table_name, manifest_url, s3_access, s3_secret)

                cur.execute(load)
                conn.commit()
        except ppg2.Error as e:
            logging.critical('Error occurred during db load: {}'.format(e))
            sys.exit(1)
        finally:
            conn.close()

    @staticmethod
    def truncate_table(schema, table, cursor):
        """
        Truncates a table given the schema and table names."""
        trunc_stmt = '''
        truncate table {}.{}
        '''.format(schema, table)

        cursor.execute(trunc_stmt)

    def execute(self):
        if self.safe_load:
            logging.info('Test load triggered, connecting now to {}.'.format(
                self.table_name
            ))
            self.copy_to_db(self.dev_db_creds,
                            self.schema_name,
                            self.table_name,
                            self.manifest_url,
                            self.s3_creds,
                            self.truncate)
            logging.info('Load to the development database was a success.')
        logging.info('Commencing load operation to {}.'.format(
            self.table_name))
        self.copy_to_db(self.prod_db_creds,
                        self.schema_name,
                        self.table_name,
                        self.manifest_url,
                        self.s3_creds,
                        self.truncate)
        logging.info('Load to the production database was a success.')
```

And how I'm calling it:

```
l1 = aws.LoadToRedshift('ods_ipeds', 'staging_ipeds_k12_faculty_counts', 's3://' + config3.S3_BUCKET + '/' + 'ipeds/K_12.csv.gz', config3.S3_INFO, config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO_PROD, dev_db_credentials=config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO, safe_load=True, truncate=True)
l1.execute()
```

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: On the command line in the Python interpreter

Comment: What is the command you are using? If you are using `ipython your_script.py` unless you have something in your script that will wait for input, then no it won't wait. Are you using `%run` from inside an ipython session?

Comment: I will include my code in the OP.